# Is super dealloc is necessary for app approval

Tags: iphone, dealloc

Will my iPhone app be approved if I do not use `[super dealloc]` in my class?

**Here i call next view controller.**

```
-(void) thumbClicked:(id) sender {

//NSArray *temp = self.mediaRecords ;
UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
if([self.mediaRecords count] > 0) {
    DetailViewViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailView.mediaArray = self.mediaRecords;
    detailView.mediaThumbs = mediaThumbs;
    detailView.currentThumbTag =  button.tag;
    detailView.tabType = currentTabType;
    detailView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    detailView.navCon = navController;
    detailView.cell = self;

    detailView.currentCellFrame = self.frame; 
    [navController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
} else {
    [CarboUtil alertWithMessage:NO_DATA_MESSAGE];
}


[detailView release];
```

}

**Here is dealloc**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    //
    LogInfo (@"Media Detail View Dealloc -- START");

    [navBar release];
    [shareView release];
    [toolBar release];
    //[category release];
    //[mediaThumbs release];
    //[mediaArray release];
    [storyWebView release];
    [buttonBorderArray release];

    [fontSizeButton release];
    [facebookButton release];
    [tweeterButton release];
    [emailButton release];
    [commentsButton release];
    [textonlyButton release];
    [saveButton release];
    [fbAgent release];
    [queue release];
    [mediaListData release];

    [super dealloc];
    LogInfo (@"Media Detail View Dealloc -- END");
}
```

but in this case dealloc never calls, i have to release view manually, and if i did it manualy i crashed on `super dealloc`

Comment: Never mind app store approval... Why would you want to avoid using [super dealloc] to begin with? That's just a bug waiting to bite, IMHO.

Comment: Potentially possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136511/does-apple-reject-leaking-iphone-apps.

Answer (score 4):

Quite possibly, but it would be a supremely stupid thing to do. Your app would likely leak like a sieve, which means you'll probably gets lots and lots of memory warnings,  which means your app will likely be pretty crashy.

In other words, learn the memory management rules. They're not that complicated.

Comment: yeah, i try to do [super dealloc] but app crashed their.

Comment: i have edit the question (put my code), please let it check. thanks